# numpy add columns to array of arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, reference

I have a np array of arrays

```
allData = np.array([[[1,2,3],[5,5,5]],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
```

I want to add a new column to each sub array. Note that the subarrays have different sizes.

by doing this:

```
toAddValue = 22    
for l in allData:
        newC = np.empty(len(l))
        newC.fill(toAddValue)
        l = np.c_[l,newC]
```

the `allData` doesn't get changed.

expected result:

```
allData = [[[  1.,   2.,   3.,  22.],[  5.,   5.,   5.,  22.]],[[  4.,   5.,   6.,  22.]],[[  7.,   8.,   9.,  22.]]]
```

I also benefit from the question to ask how can I keep the reference to `l` without loosing the same pointer when doing `l = np.c_[l,newC]` ?

Comment: What about `numpy.column_stack` ?

Comment: @plonser it's not just about adding the columns, it is also about keeping track of the modifications in the loop (on "l" variable) in the allData variable

Comment: First make `allData` a list of arrays.  Trying to work with an array of dtype object is unnecessarily complicated.  second use indexing to reference its elements.

Comment: Is `alldata` really an array of arrays, or is it a 2d or 3d array?

Comment: @hpaulj it is an array of arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `enumerate` (or `for i  in range(A.shape[0])`) you can replace the `ith` element of `A` with the new array:

```
In [91]: A=np.array([[[1,2,3],[5,5,5]],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
In [92]: A
Out[92]: array([[[1, 2, 3], [5, 5, 5]], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]], dtype=object)
In [93]: for i,l in enumerate(A):
    newC=np.empty(len(l))
    newC.fill(42)
    A[i]=np.c_[l,newC]
   ....:     
In [94]: A
Out[94]: 
array([array([[  1.,   2.,   3.,  42.],
       [  5.,   5.,   5.,  42.]]),
       array([[  4.,  42.],
       [  5.,  42.],
       [  6.,  42.]]),
       array([[  7.,  42.],
       [  8.,  42.],
       [  9.,  42.]])], dtype=object)
```

That doesn't look quite like your target, but that's becaulse `np.c_` operates on the 2d first element differently than on the 1d 2nd and 3rd.

Note that here `A`, working from your code, is an array of lists, with dtype=object.  But after the iteration, it is an array of arrays (that's because `np.c_` converts the lists to arrays when it does the concatenation).

Here's the same construction, but with a list of lists

```
In [105]: Al=list(A)
In [106]: Al
Out[106]: [[[1, 2, 3], [5, 5, 5]], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
In [107]: for i,l in enumerate(Al):
    newC=np.empty(len(l))
    newC.fill(42)
    Al[i]=np.c_[l,newC]
   .....:    
In [108]: Al
Out[108]: 
[array([[  1.,   2.,   3.,  42.],
        [  5.,   5.,   5.,  42.]]), array([[  4.,  42.],
        [  5.,  42.],
        [  6.,  42.]]), array([[  7.,  42.],
        [  8.,  42.],
        [  9.,  42.]])]
```